# What exactly is "bigint" in F#?

Tags: f#

I understand that `bigint` is not a function but rather a type constructor.  That's why this fails:

```
// Won't compile
let foo = 10 |> bigint
```

I understand that I can create a new function which accepts an integer and returns a `bigint`, and then the pipeline operator will work.

However, I don't understand why this works:

```
let bar = bigint 10
```

If `bigint` is a type constructor, why don't I need `new`?  Where exactly is `bigint` defined as an alias to System.Numerics.BigInteger's constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bigint is type abberviation for System.Numerics.BigInteger so when you type

```
let x = bigint 10
```

you actually create instance of BigInteger. In F# *new* is optional in constructors, basically it should be used when creating instances of types that implement IDisposable

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that `new` was optional. Here's a list of type abbreviations, but it omits `bigint`: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597684. I see that `int64` is also a type abbreviation. However, I believe there also is a function `int64`. I wonder why `bigint` is a type abbreviation, but `int64` is a function.

Comment: I don't know if there is a reason that, whereas all the other numeric types like "int16" are both "type abbreviations" and "functions", `bigint` is only a "type appreviaton".  I might speculate that it's because the only reason the functions like "int16" exist in the first place is to provide a way to expose primitive IL integer casts (e.g. `conv.i2`) that have no "library" calls and are typically exposed to users of other languages via "cast" features of other languages.

Comment: @Brian, insightful. But I will point out that `decimal` enjoys a conversion function form and is just a plain struct... perhaps `bigint` deserves a place too :)

Comment: @Brian,Stephen: For what its worth, `bool` has similar issues, and could probably benefit from being both an alias and a function.

Comment: also you could use type shortcuts for constants, such as:
let foo = 10I